# Can't reach the bottom of a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script in python with selenium to handle the infinite scrolling webpage. The problem I'm facing is that It scrolls few times then quits the browser. It never reaches the bottom. I tried with `Explicit Wait` as well but that gives even fewer scrolling. How can I reach the bottom when there will be no more scrolling to do.

This is my try:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from urllib.parse import urljoin

url = "https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/travelphotoawards/"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

last_len = len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".v1Nh3 a"))
new_len = last_len

while True:
    last_len = new_len
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    time.sleep(5)

    items = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".v1Nh3 a")
    new_len = len(items)
    if last_len == new_len:break

driver.quit()
```

> #### Edit:
>
> If I try like below, I can do the scrolling as many times as I want but that is not a good idea to cope with:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

url = "https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/travelphotoawards/"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

for scroll in range(1,10):  #I can do the scrolling as many times as I want but it is fully hardcoded
    item = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body")
    item.send_keys(Keys.END)
    elems = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".v1Nh3 a")
    time.sleep(3)

driver.quit()
```

I hope there is any way to do the scrolling automatically until it reaches the bottom.

Comment: Your code trials seems to be much more than simply scrolling. What is your exact usecase?

Comment: `Usecase` is totally irrelevant here cause this post is meant to do the scrolling only. Don't mislead the issue @DebanjanB.

Comment: To **do the scrolling only** you don't need `urljoin(url,item.get_attribute("href"))`. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: So, this is your original behavior @DebanjanB!! When you can't solve any issue, you came up with that very instruction and press the downvote. Before being a programmer try to grow up first. Only this portion `urljoin(url,item.get_attribute("href"))` can't make the question broad. I've added that portion to see how many valid links it can grab when the scrolling is done.

Comment: Your original question is `how many valid links it can grab when the scrolling is done`. I was trying to help you understand the **mismatch** between your _code trials_ and question description. If your question is downvoted possibly the reason is the **mismatch**. Update the question with your actual usecase for effective answers

Comment: Please, don't prolong this silly conversation anymore. To reach this statement  `how many valid links it can grab when the scrolling is done`, all I need to do first is scroll and that is what my question is.

Comment: You should try to give as much information as the people ask in order to solve an issue. That is how debugging works. If there is a code block that is uncessary and can cause issues than it's much better to remove it. Please understand that Debanjan's clarification is only for solving the issue.

Comment: Usecase would be nice: as it's not clear what you want to do with the result. If just want to just scroll, you could simulate keypress. If you want to collect all the image href's on the infinite scrolling page then you want to scroll (extract links) and scroll further, then it's a complete other story: you would probably be better of by using the instagram API. get_tags_media_recent()

Comment: So, at this point I can see my post has got 83 viewers and among them you three `demouser123`,`acidjunk`,`DebanjanB` raised a similar question about the clarity. However, if you think that very line caused you any probem to provide any solution, I'm gonna take it out. However, I'm seriously expecting any answer from either of you three. Let's see how you get there. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So few thing here. In case of infinite scrolling I would follow few things

- [Disable images](https://tarunlalwani.com/post/selenium-disable-image-loading-different-browsers/) so that the scrolling is faster
- Never trust a condition to be true if it is not consistent. Test it for it continuously for a period and if the condition is consistent then trust it
- Try to not scroll way too long, infinite scrolling can cause browser to clog too much memory and sometimes even crash
- Dump data in batches after every scroll. So on first page load, I would dump all page date. Then every scroll, I would just dump the delta part. This can be easily done using an xpath.

Below is a updated script which will do better for you. Do remember nothing is perfect, so you need to make your script adapt to failures

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from urllib.parse import urljoin

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_prefs = {}
option.experimental_options["prefs"] = chrome_prefs
chrome_prefs["profile.default_content_settings"] = {"images": 2}
chrome_prefs["profile.managed_default_content_settings"] = {"images": 2}


driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=option)

url = "https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/travelphotoawards/"

driver.get(url)

last_len = len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".v1Nh3 a"))
new_len = last_len

consistent = 0
while True:
    last_len = new_len
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    time.sleep(5)
    items = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".v1Nh3 a")
    new_len = len(items)
    if last_len == new_len:
        consistent += 1
        if consistent == 3:
            break
    else:
        consistent = 0

driver.quit()
```

Comment: It seems to be working perfectly @Tarun Lalwani. Provided plus one and gonna accept it now. I could not understand this line `if consistent == 3:`, I meant, the logic. Can you help me undestand why 3 and what it means? Thanks a lot.

Comment: It just means that when we find old length is new length then we still scroll until that condition has been seen for 3 consecutive attempts. This accounts for code making sure it has really reached the end and no more scrolling is possible. So looking into sleep(5)*consistent(3), you're making sure no extra element was added for 15 second with polling rate of 5 second

Answer (score 2):

Every time there is a scroll older images disappear. You might get the same number or even smaller number of images after the scroll.

Each image has unique `href`, you can compare the last image `href` to the previous last image

```
last_href = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.v1Nh3 > a')[-1].get_attribute('href')
new_href = last_href

while True:
    last_href = new_href
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    time.sleep(5)

    new_href = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.v1Nh3 > a')[-1].get_attribute('href')

    if last_href != new_href:
        break
```